# In an ASP.NET Core MVC view, how can I access properties of the current model?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am making a basic CRUD application in ASP.NET Core MVC that allows users to interact with a number of TV channels. When the user clicks on the "Edit" button for a particular channel, this code is run:

```
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Html.Raw(channel.ID)">Edit</a>
```

Next, the user is taken to the "Edit" view. This view contains a form with every editable property. Here is an example of the "Description" field:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Desc" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="Desc" class="form-control"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="Desc" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This field should contain the existing description, so that the user does not have to remember what it is. How can I pass this information from the "Index" view to this one?

**EDIT**

Per request, here is my full controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using TV_Channel_Manager.Models;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace TV_Channel_Manager.Controllers
{
    public class ChannelController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Channel
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:57412/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Administrator:")));

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("config/v1/project/channels");
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string responseStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    // change keys so that they match props, and convert to object
                    List<Channel> channels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Channel>>(responseStr.Replace("PROJECT_ID", "ProjID").Replace("common.ALLTYPES_DESCRIPTION", "Desc").Replace("common.ALLTYPES_NAME", "Name").Replace("servermain.CHANNEL_DIAGNOSTICS_CAPTURE", "CaptureDiag").Replace("servermain.CHANNEL_NON_NORMALIZED_FLOATING_POINT_HANDLING", "NonNormalizedFloatHandling").Replace("servermain.CHANNEL_UNIQUE_ID", "ID").Replace("servermain.CHANNEL_WRITE_OPTIMIZATIONS_DUTY_CYCLE", "WriteOptimDutyCycle").Replace("servermain.CHANNEL_WRITE_OPTIMIZATIONS_METHOD", "WriteOptimMethod").Replace("servermain.MULTIPLE_TYPES_DEVICE_DRIVER", "Driver").Replace("simulator.CHANNEL_ITEM_PERSISTENCE", "ItemPersistence").Replace("simulator.CHANNEL_ITEM_PERSISTENCE_DATA_FILE", "ItemPersistenceFile"));
                ViewData["channels"] = channels; // pass object list to view
            }
        }

        return View();
    }

    // GET: Channel/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: Channel/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Channel/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(IFormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    // GET: Channel/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Channel/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(long projID, string desc, string name, bool captureDiag, int nonNormalizedFloatHandling, long ID, int writeOptimDutyCycle, int writeOptimMethod, string driver, bool itemPersistence, string itemPersistenceFile)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:57412/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Administrator:")));

            Channel newChannelObj = new Channel(projID, desc, name, captureDiag, nonNormalizedFloatHandling, ID, writeOptimDutyCycle, writeOptimMethod, driver, itemPersistence, itemPersistenceFile);
            // replace prop names with actual names
            string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newChannelObj).Replace("\"ProjID\"", "\"PROJECT_ID\"").Replace("\"ID\"", "\"servermain.CHANNEL_UNIQUE_ID\"").Replace("Desc", "common.ALLTYPES_DESCRIPTION").Replace("Name", "common.ALLTYPES_NAME").Replace("CaptureDiag", "servermain.CHANNEL_DIAGNOSTICS_CAPTURE").Replace("NonNormalizedFloatHandling", "servermain.CHANNEL_NON_NORMALIZED_FLOATING_POINT_HANDLING").Replace("WriteOptimDutyCycle", "servermain.CHANNEL_WRITE_OPTIMIZATIONS_DUTY_CYCLE").Replace("WriteOptimMethod", "servermain.CHANNEL_WRITE_OPTIMIZATIONS_METHOD").Replace("Driver", "servermain.MULTIPLE_TYPES_DEVICE_DRIVER").Replace("\"ItemPersistence\"", "\"simulator.CHANNEL_ITEM_PERSISTENCE\"").Replace("\"ItemPersistenceFile\"", "\"simulator.CHANNEL_ITEM_PERSISTENCE_DATA_FILE\"");
            StringContent newChannel = new StringContent(serialized, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync("config/v1/project/channels/" + name, newChannel);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return View();
        }

        return NotFound();
    }

    // GET: Channel/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Channel/Delete/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id, IFormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add delete logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I suggest you do the Details view (This will work out how to get existing details and display them on the page). Edit will be almost identical, when you use the GET of Edit, you pull down existing details and display them on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, I had to change two things.

First, I had to add each parameter to my GET Edit method, and store these parameters in the ViewData array:

```
// GET: Channel/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(long projID, string desc, string name, bool captureDiag, int nonNormalizedFloatHandling, long id, int writeOptimDutyCycle, int writeOptimMethod, string driver, bool itemPersistence, string itemPersistenceFile)
    {
        ViewData["projID"] = projID;
        ViewData["desc"] = desc;
        ViewData["name"] = name;
        ViewData["captureDiag"] = captureDiag;
        ViewData["nonNormalizedFloatHandling"] = nonNormalizedFloatHandling;
        ViewData["id"] = id;
        ViewData["writeOptimDutyCycle"] = writeOptimDutyCycle;
        ViewData["writeOptimMethod"] = writeOptimMethod;
        ViewData["driver"] = driver;
        ViewData["itemPersistence"] = itemPersistence;
        ViewData["itemPersistenceFile"] = itemPersistenceFile;

        return View();
    }
```

Next, I had to add additional `asp-route-*` attributes to the Edit link in the Index view:

```
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Channel" asp-route-projid="@Html.Raw(channel.ProjID)" asp-route-desc="@Html.Raw(channel.Desc)" asp-route-name="@Html.Raw(channel.Name)" asp-route-capturediag="@Html.Raw(channel.CaptureDiag)" asp-route-nonnormalizedfloathandling="@Html.Raw(channel.NonNormalizedFloatHandling)" asp-route-id="@Html.Raw(channel.ID)" asp-route-writeoptimdutycycle="@Html.Raw(channel.WriteOptimDutyCycle)" asp-route-writeoptimmethod="@Html.Raw(channel.WriteOptimMethod)" asp-route-driver="@Html.Raw(channel.Driver)" asp-route-itempersistence="@Html.Raw(channel.ItemPersistence)" asp-route-itempersistencefile="@Html.Raw(channel.ItemPersistenceFile)">Edit</a> |
```

Doing both of these things allowed me to access each property normally in the Edit view by calling `@ViewData["<PROP>"]`, and by adding `asp-for="PROP"` tags to HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the ViewData dictionary, you can pass a model to your view.

```
return View(model);
```

In your view, set the model:

```
@model YourModelType
```

In your view, you can now access the properties using `@Model.Property`